# Show that $E[X^2])\ge \frac{4}{3} (E[X])^2$ for $X$ is supported on $(0,\infty)$ and has a monotone decreasing pdf

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

I have observed the following inequality numerically:

Suppose that random variable $X$ is supported on $(0,\infty)$ and has a monotone decreasing pdf then $$E[X^2]\ge \frac{4}{3} (E[X])^2$$.

Question: How would one prove this inequality?  This is clearly a stronger version of Jensen's or Cauchy-Schwartz which say that $E[X^2]\ge  (E[X])^2$.

Also, I am assuming something like this should be known. If so, does this inequality have a name?

Comment: Do you have an example where $=\frac43$ holds?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, I do not.

Comment: What distributions have you tried as evidence for this inequality? Have you tried finding a counterexample?

Comment: @AHusain  I tried $f(x) \sim exp(-x^k)$. I couldn't find any counterexamples.

Comment: Is that supposed to mean $f(x) = N(\sigma) \exp (-(x/\sigma)^k)$ with normalization $\sigma$ dependent? Or just with $\sigma=1$?

Comment: @AHusain  Yes, this is what it means. I only tried $\sigma=1$ and varied the $k$.